# Problem with deploying bookstore1 tutorial application on netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, sun

When I deploy bookstore1 application from Java EE 5 tutorial onnetbeans 6.7 rc1 and glassfish 2.1 I get this error:

Deploying application in domain failed; Error loading deployment descriptors for module [bookstore1] -- UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class com.sun.bookstore1.servlets.CashierServlet has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.5.0_16

Answer (score 0):

I find solution myself :

Altough in project properties Java Platform was set to 1.6 and source/binary format were also set to 1.6.  the actual sources were written in 1.5. The confliect was on the stage of trying read source format in 1.6. I set source format to 15 and everything works clean and shiny :)